# Grub Rescue - No such device on boot

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I currently have Windows 7 - 64bit Professional on my PC. I tried to install 12.10 via USB and it worked OK, I partitioned my main `C drive` and restarted my PC after Ubuntu had installed.

On boot up I get this error:

```
Error: No such device: e80420c6-e74d-4211-8854-3ce6e2f8eb48.
Grub Rescue>
```

I now cannot log onto my PC, any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from a live cd. You must install grub boot loader again. Do as I say:

1. Make a bootable usb disk and boot from it (in this way you will have a live ubuntu)
2. Mount your previous ubuntu partition in any way you know (You can do this by opening filemanager and go to partition where your ubuntu is installed on, then copy the path to this partition)
3. Then press `Ctrl+Alt+T` and open terminal, then run `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/path/to/mounted/folder/for/ubuntu/boot sda`. (make sure that you typed `sda` and `boot` at the end). In my case this is like `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/76s876sd86d8f7sdfsdf/boot sda`

Comment: Right, I'm afraid you've lost me there. Can you make your explanation more basic?

Comment: Still trying to fix this

I've managed to boot up ubuntu using my USB, I (believe) I have mounted the disk drives (although I'm not sure)

But I can't find the directory to fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks again Mostafa, I've loaded the terminal, typed sudo grab-install --boot- directory= (C:\media) sda but it doesn't work

Comment: I do have live USB on, In the terminal I've typed "Sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/00768D01768CF924 sda

I got the message Path 'media/00768D01768CF924/grub is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible Aborting.

Comment: Try this: `sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/00768D01768CF924/boot sda`

Comment: I got the same error as previous.

media/00768D01768CF924/boot/grub' is not readableby GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.

Comment: Then have a look at this http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html